# FS2 through2 closing all resources when the first stream is finished?

Tags: scala, cats-effect, fs2

Let's suppose we have 2 fs2 Streams:

```
val stream1 = fs2.Stream.bracket(IO { println("Acquire 1"); 2})(_ => IO { println("Release 1") })
  .flatMap(p => fs2.Stream.range(1,p))

val stream2 = fs2.Stream.bracket(IO { println("Acquire 2"); 4})(_ => IO { println("Release 2") })
  .flatMap(p => fs2.Stream.range(1,p))
```

which I would like to connect with each other:

```
def connect[F[_]]: (fs2.Stream[F, Int], fs2.Stream[F, Int]) => fs2.Stream[F, Int] = {
 def go(stream1: fs2.Stream[F, Int], stream2: fs2.Stream[F, Int]): Pull[F, Int, Unit] =
  stream1.pull.uncons1.flatMap { stream1Element =>
    stream2.pull.uncons1.flatMap { stream2Element =>
      (stream1Element, stream2Element) match {
        case (Some((stream1Head, stream1Tail)), Some((stream2Head, stream2Tail))) =>
          println("Some, Some")
          Pull.output1(stream1Head + stream2Head) >> go(stream1Tail, stream2Tail)
        case (Some((stream1Head, stream1Tail)), None) =>
          println("1 Stream still available")
          Pull.output1(stream1Head) >> go(fs2.Stream.empty, stream1Tail)
        case (None, Some((stream2Head, stream2Tail))) =>
          println("2 Stream still available")
          Pull.output1(stream2Head) >> go(fs2.Stream.empty, stream2Tail)
        case _ => Pull.output1(-1)
      }
    }
  }
(one, two) => go(one, two).stream
```

}

now checking logs I see:

```
Acquire 1
Acquire 2
Some, Some
Release 2
Release 1
2 Stream still available
2 Stream still available
```

which is a bit surprising for me because it seems that once the first Stream is finished the resources of the second one are closed as well. Suppose now that the resource is the connection to the database, then the elements from the second stream cannot be fetched anymore.

Is it correct behavior? Is there any way to avoid closing the resource of the second stream? Surprisingly if the first Stream has more elements than the second one, everything works as expected(stream 1's resource is not closed when the second stream is finished)

Comment: Why not just `s1.merge(s2)`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that unfortunately won't help as I don't want to simply 'merge' these streams and return all elements but apply some logic to every pair of elements.

Comment: So what about `s1.map(_.some).zipAllWith(s2.map(_.some))(None, None) { ... }`  and you put your processing logic there?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez indeed your implementation works and by checking the implementation of this function I found the answer to why uncons1 does not work as expected. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the implementation of the zipAllWith function I found out that indeed uncons1 in such cases should be avoided. The final solution would be to use the **stepLeg** function instead of uncons1. So the function from the above should look like this:

```
def connect[F[_]]: (fs2.Stream[F, Int], fs2.Stream[F, Int]) => fs2.Stream[F, Int] = {
def go(stream1: fs2.Stream[F, Int], stream2: fs2.Stream[F, Int]): Pull[F, Int, Unit] =
  stream1.pull.stepLeg.flatMap { stream1Element =>
    stream2.pull.stepLeg.flatMap { stream2Element =>
      (stream1Element, stream2Element) match {
        case (Some(sl1), Some(sl2)) =>
          println("Some, Some")
          val one = sl1.head(0)
          val two = sl2.head(0)
          Pull.output1(one + two) >> go(sl1.stream, sl2.stream)
        case (Some(sl1), None) =>
          val one = sl1.head(0)
          println("1 Stream still available")
          Pull.output1(one) >> go(sl1.stream, fs2.Stream.empty)
        case (None, Some(sl2)) =>
          val two = sl2.head(0)
          println("2 Stream still available")
          Pull.output1(two) >> go(fs2.Stream.empty, sl2.stream)
        case _ => Pull.output1(-1)
      }
    }
  }
(one, two) => {
  go(one.flatMap(fs2.Stream.emit), two.flatMap(fs2.Stream.emit)).stream
}
}
```

And the logs:

```
Acquire 1
Acquire 2
Some, Some
Release 1
2 Stream still available
2 Stream still available
Release 2
```

An additional example of this issue can be found here:
[uncons vs stepLeg](https://github.com/typelevel/fs2/issues/1678)